# Word choice: centring or centric?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, british-english

Personally I am fanatical about collecting collocations, phrases and sentences for my writing. I heard this sentence while watching a documentary and I didn't hear it well.

The two words,

- centre: around <something>, focus, concentrate (on)
- centric: meal centric, experience centric

They are synonyms of each other. However I am unable to figure out the correct word choice and usage in the following sentence. Further in my understanding centric is quite unlikely to have a preposition "on". It sounds quite odd. Thus I feel "centring" would be the right usage/choice. Can you shed some light on this?

> Sunday lunch is not simply about refueling but a relaxed communal experience **centring** on a well cooked meal.

or

> Sunday lunch is not simply about refueling but a relaxed communal experience **centric** on a well cooked meal.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that *-centric* is used more as a suffix to words rather than as a word itself. As in *egocentric* http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-centric

Comment: Do you want a British English answer?  Americans and Filipinos almost always use the spelling "center".  http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11524

Comment: I need a British English answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sentence you didn't hear properly is:

> Sunday lunch is not simply about refueling but a relaxed communal experience **centring** on a well cooked meal.

A native speaker would not use *centric on* instead of *centring on* in the sentence. Secondly, the words are not synonyms unless they have or are used as the same part of speech.

*[Centric](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/centric)* is an adjective. *[Centre](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/centre)* (US: *center*) is a verb. It is also a noun. And nouns can be used as adjectives. Rarely, adjectives can be used as nouns (*the poor*). Therefore, unless the two words are being used as the same part of speech, they are not synonyms.

As a verb *center*/*centre* is quite often followed by *on*. See *[center on](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/center+on)* and the example sentences.

Since *centre on* can be part of a verb + particle combination, the use as a gerund *centring on* is not surprising.

We use gerunds to modify nouns all the time. You can also use a *past particle* as an adjective, as in:

> Sunday lunch is not simply about refueling but a relaxed communal experience **centred** on a well cooked meal.

One can use an adjective instead of the gerund (centring) or past particple (centred):

> Sunday lunch is not simply about refueling but a relaxed communal experience **central** to the day.

*Central* is a much more common adjective than *centric*. The use of **centric to** and **centric on** is hard to find.  *Central to* is the overwhelming usage. 
[image]

You **can** find examples of *centric on* using a google search in goole books, but almost all of them are false positives, such as

> Turner mixes basketball and soul music with a James Brown-**centric** **on**-air TV campaign to hype the playoffs.

As for more on gerunds, the use of *centric* as an adjective, and how that is synonymous to the use of *-centric*, feel free to read the following.

> Sitting around the Irving Street kitchen table, they discussed rewriting the winning blueprint they'd devised thirteen years earlier. "Instead of a single recipe," he said, "why don't we do some menus building up to a party?"

Notice the noun *menus* followed by *building up to a party.* If one wanted, one could easily use *centring on/around a party* here.

> Why don't we do some menus *centring on/around a party?*

The next sentence of [my source](https://books.google.com/books?id=AVIkpbIYrEsC&pg=PA413&lpg=PA413&dq=%22meal%20centric%22&source=bl&ots=hLPA-ek-d0&sig=PvZAgBFO63lfdl2hyJOcfe384nk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=WKr6VIDDBsqNyATU5oHwAg&ved=0CFsQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=%22meal%20centric%22&f=false) is

> Julia loved the idea: a "meal-centric" program for occasions, like birthdays.

Here, the the adjective *centric* is being used with *meal* to form the [compound adjective](http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/hyphens_in_compound_adjectives.htm) *meal-centric*. A hyphen is often used when two adjectives are used as a compound adjective to desribe a noun, here *program*. Of course, *meal* is normally a noun, but like most nouns can be used as an adjective, as in *[meal ticket](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/meal+ticket)*.

And this use of *centric* is synonymous to the suffix *[-centric](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/-centric)*, meaning "having a specified centre. A *meal-centric* program is a program whose specific center is that of a meal.

Comment: If I recall correctly, the documentary was about the midieval cuisine. I really like the elements of the language used in it and I appreciate you for describing the every aspect of the topic.

Answer (score 2):

Your intuition is correct; "centring on"/"centering on" works (or "… around", for that matter), but "centric on" does not, grammatically. I am not aware of any idiom for the latter that would bend the rules, and the former is at least mildly idiomatic.

I would, however, correct your statement that they're synonyms. They're not; they're the same root in different forms that are different parts of speech. This is both closer to and farther from perfect synonymy: the meaning is closer, but there are more constraints on usage, as we see here. A gerund's valid usages are not always the same as an adjective's, especially if the adjective is, as here, more commonly hyphenated or even simply part of a larger word.

Comment: `They're not; they're the same root in different forms that are different parts of speech. This is both closer to and farther from perfect synonymy: the meaning is closer, but there are more constraints on usage, as we see here.` +1 You have picked up on the "synonymous" aspect of my question and explained quite alot of info. It is a pity there's no way except two answers.